# Regexp for handling recursive arguments

Tags: php, regex

I'm a regexp novice, so I'm wondering what the regexp for the following:

> function {function arg1, arg2}, arg3

I'm looking to be able to just select the top-level arguments: {function arg1, arg2} & arg3

Ideally the response would be using preg_match in PHP, but almost any regexp would work fine.

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: Is this the most general form of function you need? Are there always two arguments in the inner function?

Comment: If you allow an arbitrary depth of functions in arguments (`function … {function … {function …} … } … }`), your language is not regular and you cannot use a regular expression to parse it.

Comment: With the recursive pattern syntax of pcre it would be possible to _test_ the statement. But afaik the (maximum) number of captures is determined at compile-time, i.e. you would be able to either fetch the first top-level parameter + the complete tail or (not so useful) the first and the last top-level parameter (because later fetches would overwrite prior fetches for the same capture).

Comment: @Gumbo: PCRE and the like (which is of course "regex" in this context) allows you to match non-regular languages (and have been doing that for ages). I'm guessing you know this so I don't know why all the fuss about "regex can't match not regular languages".

Comment: @Qtax: To be honest, I didn’t know that PCRE does support recursive patterns. Thank you for that information.

Answer (score 0):

PCRE/Perl regex, but I'm just guessing what you want (depending on the specs below):

```
/(?:function\s+|\G(?<!^),\s*)([^,{}]+|\{function\s+(?1)\s*(?:,\s*(?1)\s*)*})\s*/g
```

**Example** Perl use:

```
test('function {function arg1, arg2}, arg3');
test('function foo, {function {function x}, y}, bar');

sub test{
    print 'Matched: "', join '", "',
        $_[0] =~
        /(?:function\s+|\G(?<!^),\s*)
        (
            [^,{}]+
            |
            \{function\s+(?1)\s*(?:,\s*(?1)\s*)*}
        )
        \s*/gx;
    print "\"\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
Matched: "{function arg1, arg2}", "arg3"
Matched: "foo", "{function {function x}, y}", "bar"
```

Should work just fine in **PHP**, just escape where needed and use with preg_match_all.

Lots of questions about the specification tho:

- Does the string you are matching on contain anything else than this?
- Are there always two arguments?
- Are arguments only one word?
- Is "function" a keyword or a function name?

More (real) examples please!

Comment: Thank you for taking a go at it - unfortunately I wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: Can we have some more (real) examples of what you want to do here?